Is it possible to use a three-phased 400V, 36A AND and additional single-phased 230V, 16 A in one machine?
We're currently still developing our machine and have made this suggestion to a building technician, who replied that he cannot imagine our machine to have these connections.
We'll work with professionals soon, but need to reply quick now, so here's our reasoning:
3-phased 400 V, 36 A = 22,5 kW

We're running 10 induction fields with peak 3 kW (half will run on 100 % power, half will run on 50 % power)

1-phased 230 V, 16 A = 3,6 kW

Running gantry systems (stepper motors), AC, Cooling and more.

Asking ChatGPT it seems, it's not uncommon to use this wiring structure, with examples being CNC machines, industrial welding machines, etc.
Is this sound or not?

Asking chatgpt is definately not sound.

It might be worth considering asking the technician about a machine needing 3 phase 400v, with an unbalanced load of 36a on 2 phases and 52A on one phase. (Conceptually the same thing)

However, depending on the nature of your single phase loads, it might be worth considering if you can split them to 3 6A circuits which can be balanced across the phases.

Please furnish details / ratings of the single phase loads.

It likely is possible - is the 3-phase equipped with neutral or not? If there are 3 phases with 400VAC between them and a neutral, you already have three separate single 230VAC phases. If you don't have a neutral, you can step down 4000VAC to 230VAC.

@user1937198 the 52 A running on 230 V?

@Justme yes, but keeping the systems separate would be beneficial. If the circuit breaker of the 400 V phases trips, the cooling ideally should keep running - unless there's an issue with that too.
Plus, a step down transformer/power supply seems costly, though you could argue that running another 230 V, 16 A wire could match the cost...

@RobinSteblea You don't need a step down if you have 3 phase wye. 400v 3 phase wye is 400v phase to phase, and 230v phase to neutral. You just connect your 230v load from a phase to neutral. As for circuit breakers, thats a electrical logicstics question as to whether it makes sense to run one larger circuit to a subpanel, or two smaller circuits.

@user1937198 oh interesting, I think I'm starting to understand it, though it's still a little unclear to me.
What about the components that run on 400 V. Usually, components are connected through live and neutral. I cannot connect one phase to another phase instead of neutral, can I? If yes, wouldn't that mean I have one phase less to use?
I have quite some learning to do!

You can just connect phase to phase. Thats how three phase motors work. They have 3 coils each of which is across one of the 3 combinations of (P1, P2), (P2, P3), (P3, P1).

@user1937198 I think I'm getting it now. So what I can do, is (P1, P2), (P2, P3), (P3, P1) at 400 V, 32 A AND (P1, N), (P2, N), (P3, N) at 230 V, 6 A each, as per your first comment?

Short Answering: Running a larger device on a main three phase supply and an additional single phase supply for auxilliary systems is relativly common.
And considering that you want cooling on the single phase it actually makes sense here to make disconnecting three phase possible whithout stopping cooling.

Agreed.  I see this all the time.  If delicate controls/electronics are in the mix, be sure to properly construct and manage the system ground (well, do that anyways) - plan for large currents on the grounding system when coupling systems like this, as they may be sourced from different transformers that are bonded at very different, perhaps far, locations (plan for the worse, get the best sandwich).

Got it, thanks. But now I've read quite often that a building usually has only 3 phases coming in, one of which will be used for most/all the 230 V, 16 A circuits.
Supposedly, leaving only 2-phases available for 400 V circuits?
Can you elaborate on that?

@RobinSteblea That may or may not be true where you live. Are you sure you understand how 3-phase system works? You get one three phase service, and those three phases are all used for evenly for 230V single phase loads and 3-phase 400V loads. At least normally in buildings.

@Justme it's the "and" that confuses me.
How do I have one three-phase service, of which I use each of them for 230 V loads and all together for 400 V(?)

@RobinSteblea Its how you rate the voltage. Single phase rate voltage as phase to neutral, whereas 3 phase wye is conventionally rated by phase to phase, which is sqrt of 3 times the phase to neutral voltage. 230v * root 3 = 400v.

So you have 400v between any two phase lines, and 230v between any of the phases and neutral.

@Justme so far so good. In Germany, it seems we have a 3 phase service in office buildings. So, if I wanted to make it really easy, can I assume 26 kW = sqrt(3) * 400 V * 41,7 A * 0,9?
Just put down some 45 A wires + breakers, a CEE 63A socket?
I'd lose the benefit of having two separate circuits though

It is standard practice to distribute the loads as shown below.

